# NullReferenceException thrown on a select case statement. Any ideas why?

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net

This error occurs occasionally in Production but I can't reproduce it in DEV

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.     
at CommandCenterHeader.ascx.vb:line 23     
at System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e)     
at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)     
at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     
at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     
at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     
at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     
at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

CommandCenterHeader.ascx.vb:line 23 is "Select Case Me.CurrentUser.UserType.ToLower"

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        Select Case Me.CurrentUser.UserType.ToLower
            Case "e", "f"
                lbtnccadmin.Visible = True
                lbtnccadmin.NavigateUrl = "/commandcenter/cc_admin.aspx"
            Case Else
                lbtnccadmin.Visible = False
        End Select
    End If
End Sub

<ComponentModel.Browsable(False)> _
    Protected ReadOnly Property CurrentUser() As CypStdLib.FL.QuotesDB.tblUserInfo
        Get
            If (Not IsNothing(Request.Cookies(cookieKey))) AndAlso (Not IsNothing(Request.Cookies(cookieKey)("userid"))) Then
                Dim uid As String = Request.Cookies(cookieKey)("userid") & ""
                If uid <> "" AndAlso IsNumeric(uid) Then
                    Dim curruser As New CypStdLib.FL.QuotesDB.tblUserInfo
                    If curruser.LoadByPrimaryKey(CLng(uid)) Then

                        Session("CurrentUser") = curruser
                        Return curruser
                    End If
                End If
            End If

            Return Nothing
        End Get
        'Set(ByVal value As CypStdLib.FL.QuotesDB.tblUserInfo)
        '    Current.Session("CurrentUser") = value
        'End Set
    End Property
```

Comment: Then is `CurrentUser`or `CurrentUser.UserType` nothing, what are they and where do you initialize them?

Comment: Eiter `Me.CurrentUser` is null or `Me.CurrentUser.UserType` is `null`; just add logging if you can't debug in production environment to check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could this be occuring when a user session has timed out in the web application?

Answer (score 1):

Clearly
The object in the hierarchy `Me.CurrentUser.UserType.ToLower`
is null.
either `Me` or `Me.CurrentUser` or `Me.CurrentUser.UserType`

If you cant think of why it could be null or what could be null..u can add a log msg just before the switch case and store it in either a file or the DB and send this code for testing purpose onto production(for sometime until u figure out whats wrong).
That will give you an idea as to what is wrong

Comment: Actually, `Me` can never be `Nothing`. So it would have to be either `CurrentUser` or `UserType`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, is `CurrentUser` null? If not, is `CurrentUser.UserType` null?

Also, `ToLower` needs to be called as a method... `ToLower()`

Comment: I think the parenthesis are optional for parameter-less methods.

Comment: VB.NET is not C#, you can call methods without parameters with or without parenthesis.